# Add fragment to url during php runtime

Tags: php, fragment

Ok so here's my situation: I have a page with 5 jquery-ui tabs, 3 of them contain a table each that is generated by php for the data, with each of them there's a set of input to filter according to the date, each table have their own form and update button. Now what I want to achieve is once I refresh and get back to the controller I want to add the corresponding fragment according to the button I pressed.

For example: If I click on the update button from the first tab I want to add #tabs-1, if it's the second one then I want to add #tabs-2.

Now I know I can do:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] . "#tabs-2";
```

Fine that gives me the correct url, but how do I make the browser go there at runtime? Is there any way to do this?

Here's a part of my controller, the main one.

```
class PageOptimisationV2C {

public static function main() {
    $class = __CLASS__;
    $c = new $class;

    $c->get();
}

public function get() {
    $this->display();
}

private function display() {
    $tpl = new PageOptimisationV2V();

    $client = ConsulterClient::getClientByNoClient(isset($_GET['cid']) ? $_GET['cid'] : 0);
    $tpl->client = $client;

    if(isset($_GET['cid'])){

        $tpl->StatsLignesCellulaire = self::buildCellStatsReport();
    }

    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] . "#tabs-2";


    $tpl->display();
} 
}
```

And then it goes on and displays the page. What would be the optimal solution to get to a fragment of the page, according to the submit button that is pressed.

I tried to make a jsFiddle to show you how the page looked but it got too messy and couldn't get the CSS to work right.

Every detail of information is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i'm aware of to do this with PHP is to do a redirect.

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'#tabs-2');
```

This of course will result in another request and require you to do some workaround with your flow but its the only way to send a new url back to the browser.

Though it isn't a runtime PHP method you can also just embed the selection Javascript, for example:

```
var index = $.index($(<?PHP echo $tab; ?>));
$('#tabs ul').tabs('select', index);
```

and allow it to go through the normal selection process.

You can also just embed a hidden element, something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="tab-selected" id="tab-selected" value="tabs-2" />
```

and have some Javascript to check if the element exists and has a value and then select the tab like this:

```
$(function() {
    if ($('#tab-selected').val()) {
        var index = $.index($('#tab-selected').val()));
        $('#tabs ul').tabs('select', index);
    }
});
```

Comment: I like your suggestions, will try that first thing in the morning when I get to work tommorow!

Answer (score 0):

Today, with a fresh mind, I thought of something else to do while reading MWJump's answer... Why not use the action attribute of the form! It's there for a reason! So for each of my form (I have one in each of my tabs) I slapped the action attribute to be the fragment of the according tab so for the first tab `action="#tabs-1"` and the second `action="#tabs2"` and so on...

I found this solution to be the simplest and easiest in this particular case.